# How do you use sed to edit a CSV file?

Tags: sed, regex

I have a CSV file like this:

```
hostname1 | role1 | environment | tag,list | |
hostname2 | role2 | environment | tag,list,longer | |
hostname3 | role3 | environment | | |
```

I need a `sed` expression that adds to the column with the tags (the 4<sup>th</sup> column) a new tag if there are no tags already, and inserts a new tag with a comma if there are existing tags. I have tried this:

```
sed "s/\(^$server |.*|.*|\) \(.*|.*|$\)/\1 new,\2/" testfile.csv
```

where server is defined externally like so:

```
server="hostname2"
```

but it doesn't work, and it doesn't deal with the comma if the tag list is empty.

How would you do this with sed?

Comment: I don't know sed scripting, but found a good tutorial here: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Answer (score 2):

A common mistakes when discovering regular expression is to think that they can be used as parser (and so you see questions like "how can I parse an XML file using REGEXs?"). However you can't insert too much logic inside a regular expression: for complex problems, like yours, you either need a parser or more than one regular expression.

If you want to go with the way of regular expressions, you need two: one for the non-empty tags case and one for the empty tags field. The two regex could look like the following ones:

```
s/^(hostname123 \|.*?\|.*?\|\s*)(\S+\s*\|.*?\|)$/\1new,\2/
s/^(hostname123 ?\|.*?\|.*?\|)\s*(\|.*?\|)$/\1 new \2/
```

These two expressions can be used either with two `sed` piped together:

```
sed 'expression1' | sed 'expression2'
```

or, better, with one command in the following way:

```
sed -r -e '/^'"$server"' \|/ { s/^(.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|\s*)(\S+\s*\|.*?\|)$/\1new,\2/; s/^(.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|)\s*(\|.*?\|)$/\1 new \2/ }' testfile.csv
```

This is more efficient than using two `sed`s because it does not parse the file twice.

Comment: wow that was quick and awesome.  But it doesn't work:                         $sed -r -e '/^$server \|/ { s/^(.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|\s*)(\S+\s*\|.*?\|)$/\1new,\2/; s/^(.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|)\s*(\|.*?\|)$/\1 new \2/ }' data2.csv
hostname1 | role1 | environment | tag,list | |
hostname2 | role2 | environment | tag,list,longer | |
hostname3 | role3 | environment | | |

Comment: Oops, sorry: the problem is that single quotes do not expand variables. The problem should be fixed now!

Comment: brilliant!  Can you explain one thing (otherwise I will ask a hundred questions).  What is the purpose of the '?'s ?  What do they do?

Comment: @Jason: I'm not a good teacher. The concept is simple, but I don't know how to explain it in a few words. What I can do is to redirect you to the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/re.html) (look for `*?, +?, ??`) which explains the concept very well, IMO.

Comment: +1 that is the most polite and considerate RTFM I have ever received.  Bravo, bravo!

Comment: Andrea, sorry, one more question _really_.   I need to expand this solution for a file with more columns.  When I add more .*?| to both buffers, it doesn't work.  Can you just clarify that I understand your regex - adding a new column ought to be a simple matter of adding another .*?\| which is zero or more non-whitespace characters non greedily up to a |.

Comment: Yes, adding a column is a matter of adding a new `.*?\|`. Note that the `|` character has a specific meaning, so it **must** be escaped. In other words `.*?|` and `.*?\|` are two completely different patterns.